# Unwind segue not fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I created an unwind segue from my UITableView prototype cell, for selection. I then put the unwind segue in the viewController I wanted to go back to.

However, when I tap a UiTableViewCell - the prepareForSegue method does not get fired and I am not taken back to the view I want to go to.

Is there a limitation to Unwind segues on UitableViewCells?

Comment: You should be able to unwind from a table view cell if that's what you're asking. Why are you using performSegueWithIdentifier:? You shouldn't be using that method if you have the segue from a cell -- you would use it if you want to unwind to one of a choice of view controllers, and in that case you would make the segue from the controller, not the cell.

Comment: I have a UITableViewController that has prototype cells in them, I created an Unwind segue from the prototype cell to the exit thing at the bottom go the UITableViewController - I then hooked it up to the unwind segue method in the view controller that I want it to go back to. It is my understanding that preparforsegue method should be called in the UITableViewController. Correct? But nothing happens and I am not taken back to the previous view controller.

Comment: Yes, prepareForSegue: should be called (you said performSegueWithIdentifier in your question). When you made the connection to the exit icon, did you choose "Selection Segue" as opposed to "Accessory Action"?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. Wasn't paying attention. I choose, "Selection Segue" as I don't have any accessory views in my cell, so it didn't seem appropriate to use that action.\

Comment: That is the correct connection, I just wanted to make sure you didn't accidentally choose the wrong one. It sounds like you've done everything correctly, so I can't think of any other reason for it failing to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help though. i have implemented a workaround for now, until i can find out why its not behaving correctly.